# Disable prompts in Windows Forms Webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, events, browser

I have a C# application which uses a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.

The problem is: i'd like the user to navigate smoothly in my application, without prompts, without javascript windows popping up, without security prompts. Even if this requires some contents to be unavailable. 
I just want to have one window (always one window, if a  receive a new window event, i redirect it to the single window). 
How can i do this?

I tried to use this.browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true but i doesnt seem to work.
For example, if i test it on a browser page which performs text validation, i still receive a popup window saying that my text is invalid.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not a post runner, i just have few questions here. If you are genuinely interested in answering this question, feel free to do so.

Comment: @lkcast i've answered both these questions at least once each over the last few days, actually, one of them several times. If you look at soem of my previous answers over the last few days (not questions, just answers) i'm sure you'll find your answers, and if you still need more help, let me know and I'll post an answer here as well. Is that ok?

Comment: No. It've found a solution somewhere else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution somewhere else, since it wasn't available here.

Here it is: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31163/Suppressing-Hosted-WebBrowser-Control-Dialogs

Basically, you have to hook the WM_INITDIALOG message.

It works wonders here.

Comment: Wow, interesting answer, does it work with JavaScript dialog boxes as well (have you tested for JavaScript)? As in, the those arising from the "Alert('hello world');" alert command in JavaScript?

Comment: Yep, it works. I just tested with your example right now. It hooks the WM_INITDIALOG message and automatically clicks the ok button before it is shown to the user.